# Changing wifi proxy settings for Android

Tags: java, android, proxy, root

I'm trying to change the wifi proxy on an android device programatically. The device can be rooted if necessary.

I've found the following code https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/8yUdQj1IOcg/zZCB87ms88kJ but I can't get it to work with any recent version of the sdk API (over v20).

There are bits and pieces over the internet that suggest it's possible like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en which doesn't actually work on my galaxy s3.

I'm not a fully proficient Android developer so I'm assuming that I'm missing something here. Again, it's fine if the device has to be rooted to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.